# use parameters taken from submit in multiple php files

Tags: php, html, database

I have several PHP files running different sql queries dealing on the same data.
In particular I insert a time interval in an html input, now, I want the same data to be used for different queries in different files, how do I proceed?

Comment: Make multiple forms that make use of the same data.

Comment: You may want to try `include`

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple files and queries and to use the same submitted variables in multiples files you  should include them in a single file
For example:

insertEmployee.php:

```
  <?php
         $fname=$_POST["fname"];
         $lname=$_POST["lname"];
         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
         $insertEmployee="INSERT into employees(firstname,lastname) values    ('$fname','$lname')";
         mysqli_query($con,$insertEmployee);
  
  ?>
```

Let us suppose there is another file:

insertEmployee2.php:

```
   <?php
       $insertSameEmployeeinAnotherTable="INSERT into employees2(firtname,lastname) values   ('$fname','$lname')";
       mysqli_query($con,$insertSameEmployeeinAnotherTable);
       mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

Now in the main file that you are submitting the values to:

main.php:

```
   <?php
      require("insertEmployee.php");
      require("insertEmployee2.php");
   ?>
```

Now in a html file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="main.php">
            <label>Enter firstname:
               <input type="text" name="fname">
            </label>
            <br>
            <label>Enter lastname:
               <input type="text" name="lname">
            </label>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Insert employee">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```